# Парсинг результатов выдачи Google. Проблема с распознаванием капчи

Tags: php, парсер, curl

Пишу парсер выдачи результатов поиска гугла. Вроде бы несложно.
Аналогичный парсер яши и мэйл работает. Но возникла проблема при скачивании картинки капчи. Упорно выдает 403 forbidden.

Делаю запрос к гуглу:

```
$url = 'https://www.google.ru/search?complete=1&hl=ru&q='.urlencode($query)...
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie_file_path);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, $cookie_file_path);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1; .NET CLR 1.0.3705; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; Media Center PC 4.0)');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $host.":".$port);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXYUSERPWD, $login.":".$pass);
$content = curl_exec($ch);

// Далее если получил редрект:
if(curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE) == 302)
{
   // .................
   // Выдираю картинку капчи и пытаюсь ее скачать
   // .................
   $captcha_image = 'http://ipv4.google.com/'.$image;
   $fh = fopen($captcha_file, 'w');
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $captcha_image);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fh);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
   curl_exec ($ch);
   fclose($fh);

   // Но вместо картинки получаю 403 forbidden.
}
curl_close($ch);
```

Пробовал при запросе картинки заново инициализировать сеанс cURL.
Результат тот же.

Содержимое файла `$cookie_file_path`:

```
# Netscape HTTP Cookie File
# http://curl.haxx.se/rfc/cookie_spec.html
# This file was generated by libcurl! Edit at your own risk.

#HttpOnly_.google.ru    TRUE    /   FALSE   1490269969  NID 87=m8iayuoh4X_H9kTM4zNlYrVmavd0qd7X6Bj1mbyZwrn23e-BQyA-GlNYBsV9iKq5cVj1ZrB9770cWf036kdakSC3tvlDIu_KVpf8yN5ilKkUk8iHAMbi_QZqD7Inlxs3
```

Comment: А куки, а реферал? Посмотрите снифером какие заголовки передаёт браузер - вам их нужно повторить, возможно даже все.

Comment: Заголовки указывал:
        'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8';
         'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate';
         'Accept-Language: ru-RU,ru;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3';
        'Connection: keep-alive';
         'Host: ipv4.google.com';
        'Proxy-Authorization: Basic cnU2MDc0MDpDNEJkWk1EMTJE';
         'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1';
        'User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1; .NET CLR 1.0.3705; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; Media Center PC 4.0)';

Результат тот же

Comment: Да никак быстро переходите, только сервисы по ручному распознаванию вам в помощь.